# Trying to replace "x" with a Remove text on Woocommerce cart

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am using WordMart theme and Woocommerce and I am trying to change the X to remove an item from the cart into the word Remove or maybe a fontawesome Garbage icon. Everything I try does not work

I have tried doing it via content in CSS and changing the × in the Woocommerce PHP code, with no luck.

```
<td class="product-remove">
<?php

echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(

'<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data- 
product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',

esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),

__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),

esc_attr( $product_id ),

esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )

), $cart_item_key );
?>
 </td>
```

I just expect for the X to be the word Remove in the simplest form, the not simple form would be a garbage icon.

Comment: Woodmart is the theme, I do not know it. The person before me decided to go with this theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the following CSS to replace the `x` with any content you want:

```
.woocommerce-cart a.remove {
   visibility:hidden!important; /*hide everything*/
   width:auto!important; /*make sure to have the need width for "remove" */
}

.woocommerce-cart a.remove:before {
   content: "Remove";
   visibility:visible; 
}
```

Comment: Note: It doesn't work on some themes like in Storefront for example.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec true, I don't think there is a generic solution as each theme will add its own styles to the same element. The main trick to override all of them.